# How to get a video card working again when the computer wakes up?

Tags: graphics-card

I have a computer with two video cards, about 50% of the time when it wakes up, one of the video cards doesn't work. The monitors connected to it are blank and the card doesn't appear on the nvidia control panel. Rebooting fixes it, but the other day I noticed that installing nvidia drivers fixed it without a reboot. Maybe if the driver re-initializes or something like that it fixes it. Does anybody know how I could do it manually without rebooting?

Comment: Perhaps try updating BIOS also to to if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause:
This could be caused by startup power requirement being so high that the second video card cannot start, it gets "starved".

**More Technical explanation:**
Too little power available at that instance, possibly leading to a "brown-out", an undefined state that requires a "reset" for recovery.

Manual "reset":
Has to be supported by the software, likely to happen when you reinstall the driver, as that implies a "restart".
Check if there is a command-line utility that has this available for the user.